# GCM works in Emulator but not in Mobile

Tags: android, android-emulator, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on GCM. I followed this [blog](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/android-push-notification-cloud-to-device-messaging/). Everything working fine on Emulator (Google API 4.3). But while testing app in real device( ver4.03), app didn't get any push messages. Device successfully registered and I update that registration_id to my third party server. In server, it got a success response from GCM.  I used different google account in emulator and device( I think this wont be the reason for this problem).

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what do  you mean by google ID? you should be using the same information

Comment: @meda google id- google account (I edited my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a deep study in my GCM implementation I found the cause of the problem. I forgot to add my package name in permission.

```
   <permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

instead of above code I set the uses-permission as

```
   <permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Its working fine in Device too. But right now, I'm wondering how this app was working perfect in emulator?

Comment: Thanks. Happend exactly this to me. It was working fine in the emulator, with a wrong value before the ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"